# Finding out the change on the [x,y] plane using core motion and gyroscope

Tags: iphone, ios, accelerometer, gyroscope, core-motion

When I tilt the iphone on the xy plane how we can get how much it has been tilted?
IPhone is being held as vertical upright position

[image: vertical up right position]

Answer (score 2):

CMMotionManager

CMMotionManager works with NSOperationQuee.
CMMotionManager provides the startAccelerometerUpadatesToQueue:withHandler method to start Core Motion data collecting.
And this method uses a threaded context by implementing an NSOperationQueue and an execution block that confomrs to the CMAccelerometerHandler format.

Core Motion data is always provided as radians. If you want degrees you will need to convert the data using the following formulas:

CGFloat DegreesToRadians(CGFloat degrees) {
   return degrees * M_PI / 180;
};

CGFloat RadiansToDegrees(CGFloat radians) {
   return radians * 180 / M_PI;
};

Comment: That i know but the problem is when i am tilting device keeping in XY plane nothing is changing in accelerate data

Comment: I do not have experience with iPhone development. To give you a pointer to dig further details, I would suggest looking for the use of gyroscope sensor. Normally, gyroscope sensor gives the change in orientation of the device along the three axis. Good luck :)